# sed - insert a line before a pattern

Tags: sed

I'd like to insert a line before a pattern with sed: 
- Insert 'XmlRootElement(name="ABC")' before "public class"

This is the script:

```
'/public class/i\@XmlRootElement(name="ABC")'
```

However I got error when I run this:

```
sed -e script testfile.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: Unterminated `s' command
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sed's I'm used to, you have to include a line break after your `i\`, and 'terminate' the insert with a blank line, i.e.

```
sed '/public class/i\
@XmlRootElement(name="ABC")

' file > outFile
```

Note, the blank line after your new inserted text.

Note, make sure you don't get any spaces at the end of the line, after the `i\`.

As I realize now that you're keeping your sed in a separate script file, the formatting constraints apply there too, just remove the `''` pair surrounding the code.

And more importantly, your script is failing because you use `-e` for a sed script file, use

```
sed -f script testfile.txt
```

`-e` is used if your embedding your sed script in-line, My 1st solution above could be pre-pended with `-e`.

**Edit** Fixed references to `a\` to `i\'. Doah

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. It works! Fyi, I used sed for windows in UnxUtils.zip. The script is put in a text file works when removing the single quotes

Comment: Yes, just completed edit, mentioning that option. Thanks for the vote. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
# cat <<\! >/tmp/test.sed
> /^aaa/i\
> xxx
> /^bbb/a\
> yyy\
> zzz
> /^ccc/c\
> the end
> !
# echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc" | sed -f /tmp/test.sed 
xxx
aaa
bbb
yyy
zzz
the end
```

or from the command line:

```
# echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc" | sed -e '/^aaa/i\xxx' -e '/^bbb/a\yyy\nzzz' -e '/ccc/c\the end'
xxx
aaa
bbb
yyy
zzz
the end
```

A very useful reference is [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq.html)